# why can you rewrite $\sqrt{\sec^2(x)}$ as $|\sec(x)|$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Im currently solving for the derivative of $e^{\sqrt{\sec^2(u)}}$ and the online calculator rewrote the equation as just $e^{|\sec(u)|}$. Why did they do that. I tried solving for the derivative without rewriting it but got a completely different answer.

Comment: Could you explain what is "sec"?

Comment: Because $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$?

Comment: @lulu: What if $u$ and $\sec(u)$ are not real?

Comment: @tomasz given that the original posting contains the *trigonometry* tag and does not contain the *Complex Analysis* tag, it is reasonable to presume that $u$ and $\sec(u)$ are real.  So, complications around the comparison of $\sqrt{z^2}$ versus $|z|$, for $z \in \Bbb{C}$ are probably not intended by the original poster.

Comment: @user2661923: It was a joke.

Comment: @AnneAunyme ... $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. We can see that $f(x)^2$ will always be a positive number.

Now, we will take the square root. In normal cases, which is the case with your function, the square root function of any real, nonnegative number **by definition** will always return the *principal* root, that is to say, the nonnegative root.

Hence, $\sqrt{f(x)^2}=|f(x)|$. If we let $f(x)=\sec(x)$, then $\sqrt{f(x)^2}=|\sec(x)|$. this demonstrates your question.